# Unwanted cascade delete by Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, cascade

I am working on a product catalog, and have two entities, PcatSalesItem and PcatCategory with a many-to-many relationship between them. If I delete a category, and there are still sales items associated with it, I want an exception to be thrown, I do NOT want cascading delete. On the RDBMS level (PostgreSQL), in the join table, I have set the foreign keys to "ON DELETE RESTRICT". However, when I delete a category that has sales items, Doctrine does a cascading delete. Nowhere have I specified cascade=remove to Doctrine!

Here are the entities:

```
/**
 * PcatSalesItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pcat_sales_item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Loggable(logEntryClass="Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Entity\Business\LogEntryBusiness")
 */
class PcatSalesItem
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="pcat_sales_item_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var array $categories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PcatCategory")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pcat_category_x_sales_item",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sales_item_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="RESTRICT")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="RESTRICT")}
     *      )
     */
    private $categories;
    ...
}

/**
 * PcatCategory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pcat_category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Loggable(logEntryClass="Qi\Bss\BaseBundle\Entity\Business\LogEntryBusiness")
 */
class PcatCategory
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="pcat_category_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var array $salesItems
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PcatSalesItem")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="pcat_category_x_sales_item",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="RESTRICT")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sales_item_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="RESTRICT")}
     *      )
     */
    private $salesItems;
    ....
}
```

Here is the code I use to delete a category:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$cat = $em->getRepository('QiBssBaseBundle:PcatCategory')->find(15);
$em->remove($cat);
$em->flush();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've had similiar problems using `cascade=all`; your answer is on this page: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: I have read that page earlier on, but do not see the answer there. it clearly says; "By default, no operations are cascaded".